# Creating device driver which feeds GPS Co-ordinates from phone to raspberry pi

Tags: bluetooth, kernel, driver, gps, input-device

I don't have GPS module, so I was thinking whether I can feed GPS coordinates from my android/ios phone to raspberry pi over wireless protocol like bluetooth/TCPIP.

Can I create a virtual device driver which will emulate GPS module, but internally it is just returning values received over bluetooth/TCPIP.

e.g.-> It should appear as /dev/ttyXYZ and should return values recived over bluetooth /TCPIP

Comment: we do not know anything about you, so we cannot possibly know if you have the skill to create the virtual device driver.

Comment: @jsotola I do have basic knowledge of device drivers,operating systems and embedded systems, have created various projects using pi and python. I am ready to go extra mile in any direction to get this working

Comment: I would say, yes it is possible to create a virtual device driver which will emulate GPS module. I suggest to start now programming it. If you encounter specific problems you can ask again for details. Your question now is too broad. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.